# AWS instance accessible by IP only and not with domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an instance running on AWS. I have stopped it and then restarted it after few hours. Now I am unable to access my website by a domain name but it is accessible by its ip

Looking for a solution so that I am able to access it with domain name also.

Comment: Which domain name, the AWS provided one or your own? Was the domain working before?

Comment: its my personal domain. It was working perfectly fine before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this is your personal domain, the likely scenario is that when your instance rebooted the IP address changed.

You can validate this by comparing the public IP address in the AWS Console to the IP address entered in your DNS configuration for your domain.

This is expected behaviour for the standard public IP address for EC2 hosts, if you want to resolve this you will need to [create an elastic IP address and associate it to the instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html#using-instance-addressing-eips-allocating) you have.

Once this has been associated update your DNS record to use the new public IP that has been assigned (the EIP). This will then allow you to reboot your instance without the risk of losing your IP. In addition be aware that based on the TTL of your domain you will need to wait for the DNS to propagate.

Comment: THanks. I have updated the Ip address and added Public IP address of Insance in the Record Name Type (A) . No error occurs but currently it is still inaccessible by IP address. How much time it will take for DNS to be updated?

Comment: @Eshban What do you mean by "still inaccessible by IP address"? Which IP address are you using to connect? Also, _how_ are you connecting -- is it via SSH, RDP, or web? The IP addresses are available for use immediately.

Comment: @john Rotenstein: My typo. Still unable to access via website url

Comment: You should have a TTL for the A record visible, this is the number of seconds the record is cached for. If you do a dig command from your local or even ping it you should get the IP address your local machine is resolving it to :)

Comment: TTL value is 300 seconds but when ping the public IP address of any of my instance in Windows 10 I received an error "Request Timed out" only.

Comment: There is also a test record option. When I test the record type (NS - Nameservers for Hosted zone) I did not receive any error but only issue is that I am unable to access my website via domain name

Comment: Request timed out is fine, thats because of security group not allowing ping. Presumably that is now resolving to the IP of the server correctly? Do you have any error messages when you try to access your website?

Comment: I get this error: This site can’t be reached.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Running Windows Network Diagnostics
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: Hmm, I presume you also do not have any strict security group rules? Are you 100% sure you're now accessing the correct IP? Try accessing in a private incognito window or different browser too as some browsers cache.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220538/discussion-between-eshban-and-chris-williams).